# Error: Widget selecciona todas las opción de un radioGroup

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo un RadioListTile que al ser llamada me selecciona todas las opciones que tengo disponible cuando quiero que este inicialice sin seleccionar una opción. Ademas de que no se puede deseleccionar las opciones.

```
class RadioButtonListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  RadioButtonListTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.options,
    required this.label,
  }) : super(key: key);
  List<RadioValue> options;
  final String label;
  @override
  _RadioButtonListTileState createState() => _RadioButtonListTileState();
}

class _RadioButtonListTileState extends State<RadioButtonListTile> {
  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: List.generate(widget.options.length, (index) {
        final option = widget.options[index];
        return RadioListTile<bool>(
          title: Text(option.option),
          value: false,
          groupValue: widget.options[index].isSelected,
          onChanged: (bool? value) {
            setState(() {
              widget.options[index].isSelected = value!;
            });
          },
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Estos son los datos que le paso al widget

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Necesitas repasar los conceptos básicos de Flutter, Stateless, Stateful,etc.

El valor de tus radio buttons tienen "false"  

RadioListTile<bool>(
          title: Text(option.option),
          value: false,

TODOS

El valor seleccionado es:   groupValue: widget.options[index].isSelected, 

Que al inicio es FALSE, por eso todos aparecen como seleccionados.

En el setState, estás usando variables del widget padre, no del hijo.  onChanged: (bool? value) {
            setState(() {
              widget.options[index].isSelected = value!;
            });
          },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tienes el valor inicial del RadioButton en `false`, esto no te permitirá cambiar el valor del radioButton, para poder manejar el estado de un radioButton te recomiendo declarar variables `int` de clase, a continuación te dejo un ejemplo:

```
class _RadioButtonListTileState extends State<RadioButtonListTile> {

  int? value = 1; 
   

  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: List.generate(widget.options.length, (index) {
        final option = widget.options[index];
        return RadioListTile<int?>(
          title: Text(option.option),
          value: value,
          groupValue: widget.options[index].isSelected,//deberia ser un identificador único(int)
          onChanged: (int? value) {
            setState(() {
             //aquí actualizarás el valor del widget.options con 
             //el valor de la variable value (1) y así no se te 
             //marcarían todas las opciones
             widget.options[index].isSelected = value!;
           })            
          },
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

El `groupValue` es un identificador para poder saber qué `radioButton` trabajan en conjunto.

Acá te dejo un ejemplo que acabé de hacer:

```
  class _PruebRadioListState extends State<PruebRadioList> {
  int? grupo = 0;
  int? value = 1;
  int? value2 = 2;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          RadioListTile<int?>(
            onChanged: (int? value) {
              setState(() {
                grupo = value!;
              });
            },
            groupValue: grupo,
            value: value,
          ),
          RadioListTile<int?>(
            onChanged: (int? value) {
              setState(() {
                grupo = value!;
              });
            },
            groupValue: grupo,
            value: value2,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Si funciono, gracias por tu ayuda